# Store all images uploaded to website in specific directory

Tags: 7, nodes, media, files

I have been using various image gallery modules, customised views galleries/ slideshow and my images are ending up in multiple directories also stored as different sizes e.g. thumbnail, medium, large... [image]

Is there also a way (maybe a script) to delete the file from anywhere in the directory when the node that holds the images is deleted?

Comment: I hope below link will help you.

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47967/files-attached-to-nodes-are-never-deleted-from-server-even-after-theyre-removed

Comment: @PremPatel back in 2012 that may have been that case, I don't believe it is now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there also a way (maybe a script) to delete the file from anywhere
>   in the directory when the node that holds the images is deleted?

They get auto deleted when cron runs.